# why bash script adds single quotes on variable expansion?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to use bash script to add resolution through xrandr and i keep getting error, here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

out=`cvt 1500 800`
out=`echo $out | sed 's/\(.*\)MHz\(.*\)/\2/g'`
input=`echo $out | sed 's/Modeline//g'`
#echo $input
xrandr --newmode $input
input2=`echo $out | cut -d\" -f2`
#echo $input2
xrandr --addmode VNC-0 $input2
```

running with bash -x

```
input=' "1504x800_60.00" 98.00 1504 1584 1736 1968 800 803 813 831 -hsync +vsync'
+ xrandr --newmode '"1504x800_60.00"' 98.00 1504 1584 1736 1968 800 803 813 831 -hsync +vsync
```

if you look at the last line, it adds for some reason single quote ' at the start (before ") and after ", why ??

Comment: Take a look at: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: it is adding ' to the double quotes for some reason

Comment: it is safe to run, you can try it out, when i see do the same steps manually, it works out fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singe quotes are added by `bash -x` when printing debug output.

It won't affect your actual variables value:

```
out=`cvt 1500 800`
echo $out
# 1504x800 59.92 Hz (CVT) hsync: 49.80 kHz; pclk: 98.00 MHz Modeline "1504x800_60.00" 98.00 1504 1584 1736 1968 800 803 813 831 -hsync +vsync
echo $input
"1504x800_60.00" 98.00 1504 1584 1736 1968 800 803 813 831 -hsync +vsync 98.00 1504 1584 1736 1968 800 803 813 831 -hsync +vsync
```

What's actually happens, that quotes inside a variable's value aren't parsed when the variable is substituted.

The best way to do this sort of thing is using an array instead of a simple text variable:

```
xrandr_opts=() # declaring array
input=`echo $out | sed 's/Modeline//g'`
read -a xrandr_opts <<< $input # splitting $input to array
xrandr --newmode "${xrandr_opts[@]}"
```

As for your specific case, following change will do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

out=`cvt 1500 800`
out=`echo $out | sed 's/\(.*\)MHz\(.*\)/\2/g'`
input=`echo $out | sed 's/Modeline//g'`
#echo $input
#xrandr --verbose --newmode $input
xrandr_opts=() # declaring array
input=`echo $input | sed 's/\"//g'`
read -a xrandr_opts <<< $input # splitting $input to array
opts_size=`echo ${#xrandr_opts[@]}`
xrandr --newmode `printf \'\"%s\"\' ${xrandr_opts[0]}`      
${xrandr_opts[@]:1:$opts_size}
input2=`echo $out | cut -d\" -f2`
#echo $input2
xrandr --verbose --addmode VNC-0 $input2
```

Looks like `xrandr --newmode` won't accept double quotes. I can't say exactly what's the reason, but at least the script works :)

Comment: didnt help, same result

Comment: some error that xrandr issues about not finding the mode, try to run the script and you'll see, when printing the commands from the script and running them manually, they work fine

Comment: i ran your script on fedora/redhat, it is still not working, but i understand your point..

Comment: Strange, It worked for me on CentOS. Do you still getting error on `xrandr --newmode `printf \'\"%s\"\' ${xrandr_opts[0]}` or on `xrandr --verbose --addmode VNC-0 $input2` or both?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81844/discussion-between-samuel-and-shd).